# ar.js with cordova and ionic2 - video not showing, but 3d AR objects do

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ar.js

I have a demo ar.js project from the github repository  working with cordova 6.3.1 showing a torus knot when the marker (hiro) comes into the webcam view.  I am currently using simulator for android with Chrome.

When I combined into a project with the ionic 2 platform, the video quit showing.  I am still able to see the overlay 3d graphic of the torus knot when the hiro marker comes into view of the camera, but not the video stream from the camera which is needed to know when the marker is in view.

When I comment ion-app section out of the index.html file, then the video shows, but none of the ionic components.

I have tried what I can think of including varying the z-index, trying to vary transparency / opacity background-color of ionic components on the page via the local and variables.scss files and making the renderer.domElement a child node of a div that is outside of the ion-content.  Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated on how to get the video to show.

Comment: try to add your video in aframe and get using iframe.

Comment: @user9088454 Thanks, I will take another look at aframe.  I initially tried aframe with an example where I saw them put the video into the scene as a texture on a polygon in the background, but I was getting an error that the video wasn't a power of 2,  I tried to scale it to 256x256, but was still getting the error.  Will revisit

Comment: @user9088454 Thanks.  I wasn't familiar with iframe.  I was able to get my original code to work within the iframe element.  Here is a reference link for others looking to solve similar problem.  https://www.joshmorony.com/augmented-reality-in-an-ionic-angular-pwa/